# Exporting data from hdfs to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, scala, hadoop

I am trying to move data from hdfs to mongodb. I am able to achieve this through command line like below.

```
hadoop fs -text "/user/name.txt" | mongoimport --host 127.0.0.1:27018 -d cds -c hello --type tsv --headerline
```

I need to write  a scala code for this. I have multiple files in the file-system. I have checked mongo-hadoop  connector but I need the opposite of this. Reading files from hdfs and dumping into mongodb in scala.

Comment: Apache Spark has Mongo connectors... Anyways, depending on the data source, if all you're doing is downloading a text file and streaming it to MongoImport, maybe HDFS isn't needed

Comment: Also, did you misread that library? *allows MongoDB (or backup files in its data format, BSON) to be used as an input source, **or output destination***

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways for doing the same, Since the above runs as single threaded application you can even run the same distributed by just introducing a simple MR like this [complete note here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/wiki/Sensor-Logs-Example)

```
public class LogReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, NullWritable, MongoUpdateWritable> {

    @Override
    public void reduce( final Text pKey,
                        final Iterable<IntWritable> pValues,
                        final Context pContext )
            throws IOException, InterruptedException{

        int count = 0;
        for(IntWritable val : pValues){
            count += val.get();
        }

        BasicBSONObject query = new BasicBSONObject("devices", new ObjectId(pKey.toString()));
        BasicBSONObject update = new BasicBSONObject("$inc", new BasicBSONObject("logs_count", count));
        pContext.write(null, new MongoUpdateWritable(query, update, true, false));
    }

}
```

Or by hive table as stated [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/wiki/Hive-Usage#limitations-of-mongostoragehandler) without needing to write much code. 
Or by spark here

```
package com.mongodb.spark_examples;

import com.mongodb.spark.MongoSpark;
import com.mongodb.spark.config.WriteConfig;

import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

import org.bson.Document;

import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public final class WriteToMongoDBWriteConfig {

  public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local")
      .appName("MongoSparkConnectorIntro")
      .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.myCollection")
      .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.myCollection")
      .getOrCreate();

    JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());

    // Create a custom WriteConfig
    Map<String, String> writeOverrides = new HashMap<String, String>();
    writeOverrides.put("collection", "spark");
    writeOverrides.put("writeConcern.w", "majority");
    WriteConfig writeConfig = WriteConfig.create(jsc).withOptions(writeOverrides);

    // Create a RDD of 10 documents
    JavaRDD<Document> sparkDocuments = jsc.parallelize(asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)).map
         (new Function<Integer, Document>() {
       public Document call(final Integer i) throws Exception {
               return Document.parse("{spark: " + i + "}");
             }
      });

    /*Start Example: Save data from RDD to MongoDB*****************/
    MongoSpark.save(sparkDocuments, writeConfig);
    /*End Example**************************************************/

    jsc.close();

  }

}
```

Scala

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local")
      .appName("MongoSparkConnectorIntro")
      .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://192.168.2.13:28111,192.168.2.14:28112,192.168.2.15:28113/test.myCollection")
      .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://192.168.2.13:28111,192.168.2.14:28112,192.168.2.15:28113/test.myCollection")
      .getOrCreate()
    import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

    val writeConfig = WriteConfig(Map("collection" -> "spark", "writeConcern.w" -> "majority"), Some(WriteConfig(spark.sparkContext)))
    val sparkDocuments = spark.sparkContext.parallelize((1 to 10).map(i => Document.parse(s"{spark: $i}")))

    MongoSpark.save(sparkDocuments, writeConfig)

  }
```